# Syntax error on token “Invalid Character”, delete this token

Tags: java, eclipse

I had a problem with my Eclipse, I am using MAC OS.

I don't know why it says error: "Syntax error on token “Invalid Character”, delete this token". May anyone tell me why? I've googling somewhere but can't found how to solve this issue.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
package _Java_tuan1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date {
    private String month;
    private int day, year;

    public Date(){
        month = "January";
        day = 1;
        year = 1000;
    }

    ￼public Date(int monthInt, int day, int year){
        setDate(monthInt, day, year);
    }   

    ￼public Date(String monthString, int day, int year){
        setDate(monthString, day, year);
    }

    ￼public Date(int year){
        setDate(1, 1, year);
    }

    public Date(Date aDate){
        if (aDate == null){
             System.out.println("Fatal Error.");
             System.exit(0);
        }
        month = aDate.month;
        day = aDate.day;
        year = aDate.year;
    }

    public void setDate(int monthInt, int day, int year){
        if(dateOK(monthInt, day, year)){
            this.month = monthString(monthInt);
            this.day = day;
            this.year = year;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void setDate(String monthString, int day, int year){
        if(dateOK(monthString, day, year)){
            this.month = monthString;
            this.day = day;
            this.year = year;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void setDate(int year){
        setDate(1, 1, year);
    }

    public void setYear(int year){
        if( (year < 1000) || (year > 9999)){
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            this.year = year;
        }
    }

    public void setMonth(int monthNumber){
        if((monthNumber <= 0) || (monthNumber > 12)){
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            month = monthString(monthNumber);
        }
    }

    public void setDay(int day){
        if((day <= 0) || (day > 31)){
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            this.day = day;
        }
    }

    public int getMonth(){
        if(month.equals("January")){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(month.equals("February")){
            return 2;
        }
        else if(month.equals("March")){
            return 3;
        }
        else if(month.equals("April")){
            return 4;
        }
        else if(month.equals("May")){
            return 5;
        }
        else if(month.equals("June")){
            return 6;
        }
        else if(month.equals("July")){
            return 7;
        }
        else if(month.equals("August")){
            return 8;
        }
        else if(month.equals("Septemper")){
            return 9;
        }
        else if(month.equals("October")){
            return 10;
        }
        else if(month.equals("November")){
            return 11;
        }
        else if(month.equals("December")){
            return 12;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return (month +" "+day+", "+year);
    }

    public boolean equals(Date otherDate){
    ￼￼    return ((month.equals(otherDate.month)) && (day == otherDate.day) && (year == otherDate.year));
    }

    public boolean precedes(Date otherDay){
        return ( (year < otherDay.year) || (year == otherDay.year) && getMonth() < otherDay.getMonth() ||
                (year == otherDay.year && month.equals(otherDay.month) && day < otherDay.day));
    }

    public void readInput(){
        boolean tryAgain = true;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(tryAgain){
            System.out.println("Enter month, day, and year.");
            System.out.println("Do not use a comma.");
            String monthInput = keyboard.next();
            int dayInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            int yearInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (dateOK(monthInput, dayInput, yearInput) ){
                setDate(monthInput, dayInput, yearInput);
                tryAgain = false;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Illegal date. Reenter input.");
        }
    }

    private boolean dateOK(int monthInt, int dayInt, int yearInt){
        return ( (monthInt >= 1) && (monthInt <= 12) && (dayInt >= 1) && (dayInt <= 31) && 
                (yearInt >= 1000) && (yearInt <= 9999) );
    }

    private boolean dateOK(String monthString, int dayInt, int yearInt){
        return (monthOK(monthString) && (dayInt >= 1) && (dayInt <= 31) && (yearInt >= 1000) && (yearInt <= 9999));
    }

    private boolean monthOK(String month){
        return (month.equals("January") 
                || month.equals("February") 
                || month.equals("March") 
                || month.equals("April")
                || month.equals("May")
                || month.equals("May")
                || month.equals("May")
                || month.equals("June")
                || month.equals("July")
                || month.equals("August")
                || month.equals("Septemper")
                || month.equals("Octobor")
                || month.equals("November")
                || month.equals("December"));                                   
    }

    private String monthString(int monthNumber){
        switch(monthNumber){
            case 1: return "January";
            case 2: return "February";
            case 3: return "March";
            case 4: return "April";
            case 5: return "May";
            case 6: return "June";
            case 7: return "July";
            case 8: return "August";
            case 9: return "Septemper";
            case 10: return "October";
            case 11: return "November";
            case 12: return "December";
            default: 
                System.out.println("Fatal Error");
                System.exit(0);
                return "Error";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you paste your code instead of image..not able to see the code

Comment: I've updated, please check again.

Comment: You've got some invisible characters in there. Just erase everything in between those constructor and reformat.

Comment: Is it only telling you the line the problem is on, or the exact character it considers invalid? Have you edited this file on another system or in another editor at some point, or pasted the contents in from elsewhere?

Comment: I reenter them and it work, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have you pasted the code from Windows?
Delete the last few characters and re-enter them - I think it will go away